# Flex responsive for mobile

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Good day.

I have example flex layout

```html
<style>
.items {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
.items .item {
    flex: 1 0 200px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #e0ddd5;
    color: #171e42;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
</style>
<div class="items">
    <div class="item">Heriberto Nickel</div>
    <div class="item">Brittaney Haliburton</div>
    <div class="item">Maritza Winkler</div>
    <div class="item">Carmon Rigg</div>
    <div class="item">Alice Marmon</div>
    <div class="item">Lyman Steakley</div>
    <div class="item">Zenia Correa</div>
</div>
```

And so when I'm the size of the browser window, everything works correctly (see picture below)

[image]

But if i use dev tools chrome (see picture below)

[image]

you can see that everything is working incorrectly - I need every line under each other.  (see picture below)

[image]

Please tell me how to fix it. Thank

Comment: you have to use **width: 100%;** and **display: block;**.

Comment: In the screenshot, the width of the device is `526px`, your first screenshot is smaller than this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A really easy fix would be to add this into the `<head>` of your .html file:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">`

Maybe you have to change the number from `initial-scale=`, depending if all elements are too big or too small.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Your option works! I would like to like you, but I do not have enough reputation  [enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjrJf.png

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that. You can still mark my answer as best answer (green checkmark): https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer - That would help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `.items` to `flex: 1 0 100%` initially, instead of 200px, this will force each element to sit on its own line then use a media query to set the `flex-basis` of the `.item` elements to 200px when the viewport is at a particular width or larger.

In the example below I have specified that the viewport must be at least 400px in width to trigger the change but you can change this to whatever value fits your purpose.

You can read more about [media queries here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/#css-media-queries).

```html
<style>
.items {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
.items .item {
    flex: 1 0 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #e0ddd5;
    color: #171e42;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  .items .item {
    flex-basis: 200px;
  }
}
</style>
<div class="items">
    <div class="item">Heriberto Nickel</div>
    <div class="item">Brittaney Haliburton</div>
    <div class="item">Maritza Winkler</div>
    <div class="item">Carmon Rigg</div>
    <div class="item">Alice Marmon</div>
    <div class="item">Lyman Steakley</div>
    <div class="item">Zenia Correa</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Only initially I need the columns to be in a row.

Comment: So on smaller screens, you want the `.items` to be in column one below the other but and on larger screens, they should be in a row next to each other?